# Getting student name from student table belonging to a section with less than 5 students enrolled

Tags: sql, oracle, count

[image: enrollment table]
[image: student table]

Hello there, I have a questions for you guys. You see enrollment and student table in images below. I want to run a query getting first and last name from student table but students should belong to a section with less than 5 enrolled students.

Does that make any sense? If i am not clear please do ask me a question. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tried anything? Join and having would be the two things I'd expect to see in there...

Comment: Yes I did and Marcelo's answer works for me. It is simple and got the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT s.FIRST_NAME, s.LAST_NAME
FROM student s
WHERE s.STUDENT_ID IN (
    SELECT e1.STUDENT_ID
    FROM e1.enrollment
    WHERE e1.SECTION_ID IN (
        SELECT e2.SECTION_ID
        FROM e2.enrollment
        GROUP BY e2.SECTION_ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e2.STUDENT_ID) < 5
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Marcelo for your answer, it is easy for me to understand and I got the result I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why access one table more than once, if you can save some work by using analytic functions?

```
select
  first_name, last_name
from 
  (
    select
      s.first_name, s.last_name, count(*) over(partition by e.section_id) as enrollment_count
    from 
      student s
      join enrollment e using (student_id)
  )
where
  enrollment_count < 5;
```

Comment: Thank you Balazs for the answer, I have tried it on the database and got the answer I wanted. Thanks again

Comment: But I will choose Marcelo's answer only because it is easier for me to understand his answer, I still consider myself as a beginner in SQL and I don't understand 'partition' functions yet. Thanks again

Comment: @Ali, early on, it is very useful to learn how to use [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009) (accessible also throught the right click menu in SQLDeveloper) for evaluating a query performance-wise. Using this method, you should see that @Balazs's solution has a much smaller _cost_ when compared to the accepted answer. If you don't yet understand analytic functions, you should definitely get to know them better -- there are lots of good tutorials out there, such as [this one](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55).

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thank you for the feedback, and I actually was looking for tutorials like the one you mentioned in your post. I will go through all the analytic functions. Then I will find a detailed sub query tutorial, want to know where can i place a sub-query. 

I have seen ppl put a sub-query after FROM and sometimes after WHERE key word. Just need some more info on it, again thank you for taking time and posting comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.first_name, t2.last_name
from table2 t2
inner join 
    (select student_id from table1 where section_id in 
        (select section_id from 
            (select section_id, count(student_id) 
                from table1
                group by section_id
                having count(student_id) < 5
            )
        )
    )t1
on t1.student_id = t2.student_id;
```

Its not pretty, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I have tried it and it works.